# Checking for pattern after date and time

Tags: shell, logging, pattern-matching

There are log files in which there are patterns

```
----- Fri Mar 22 20:11:50 2013
statement 1
statement 2
statement 3
.
.
.
No errors
statement 10
statement 11
statement 12
```

I need to search present date and time log generated and look for pattern "No Errors" in log file. How can I do that ? 
small note : log files will contain multiple day log entries.

I tried

```
 [ `grep -c "No Errors"  /usr/apps/logs/errrors.log` eq 1 ]
 echo "No error"
```

Issue is it does not echo "No Error" as it might have more than one match here. SO how do I 
find a pattern after certain checking time and date in log file ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Do this in two separate commands piped together. The first part of the command will print matches of either dates or the string "No errors." The second part will remove duplicate adjacent lines of output, so that at most there is one "No errors" printed between each date.

```
grep -ei '[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] 20[0-9][0-9]' -ei 'No errors' | uniq
```

The output you get will be a listing of dates followed by message 'No errors' after the date, if there were any occurence(s) of the string 'No errors' after that date and prior to the next date contained in the log file.

I'm not sure if your file contains "No error" or "No errors" so make sure that my command is updated to exactly what you are searching for. Also, make sure that you change the command so that it receives input from the logfile you are working with. For example,

```
cat logfile | grep -ei ......
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like `awk` where you can define the record separator and field separator. I can't test since you didn't supply much sample input, but something like this might work:

```
awk -v RS='----- ' -v FS='\n' '/No errors/ {print "No errors on " $1}' logfile
```